# curl can't list directory in ftp directory?

Tags: curl

```
curl  -l  ftp://192.168.31.174:3721
IBOX
calculators
Pictures
.system
Download
DCIM
```

I want to list  all files in DCIM.

```
 curl  -l  ftp://192.168.31.174:3721/DCIM
```

curl can't list directory in ftp directory?

Comment: Is the FTP server itself allowed to execute and read the directory + files in it? What permissions and owners do you have. Provide details please.

Comment: And try without `-l` since some FTP server software doesn't include sub-directories and symbolic links in the output when that is used!